# Laravel Update field, with another field value

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table of items, it contains the 2 fields : PLEVEL1 and PRINTOU3:

I'm sending to the update function percentage parameter and I want to update PLEVEL1 WITH PRINTOUT3 LIKE THAT:

```
public function updatePrice($brandid, $itemgroup, $percentage){
$update=DB::table('sd_salesitems')->where('BRAND_ID', $brandid)
                                  ->where('SL_GROUP', $itemgroup)
       ->update(array('PLEVEL1' => 'PRINTOUT3'+'PRINTOUT3'*$percentage/100)); }
```

It's updating to 0 and that's not correct, any idea ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use this :

```
DB::table('sd_salesitems')
        ->update([
            "bumped_last" => DB::raw("`PRINTOUT3 `+`PRINTOUT3`*".($percentage/100))
        ]);
```